# SCORM 1.2: changing when cmi.core.lesson_status is updated to fail (articulate rise)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scorm, scorm1.2

Hoping there is a SCORM/Javascript pro out there who can help this noob!

I have a SCORM file authored in Articulate Rise. Initially the cmi.core.lesson_status is set to "incomplete". At the end there is a quiz which allows two attempts. After the first failed attempt, the lesson_status updates to "failed". It stays that way unless you pass.

Instead, I want it to stay as "incomplete" after the first attempt if you fail. Then, after the second attempt, I want it to update to "passed" or "failed" based on your score.

Here is how the code was written orginally:

```
var reporting = 'passed-failed';

function completeOut(passed, reportParam) {
  var reportType = reportParam || reporting;

  if(passed) {
    switch(reportType) {
      case 'completed-incomplete':
      case 'completed-failed':
        LMSProxy.ResetStatus();
        LMSProxy.SetReachedEnd();
        break;

      case 'passed-incomplete':
      case 'passed-failed':
        LMSProxy.SetPassed();
        LMSProxy.SetReachedEnd();
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch(reportType) {
      case 'passed-failed':
      case 'completed-failed':
        if(!isPassed()) {
          LMSProxy.SetFailed();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

After looking at it, I tried to fix it with this code. Note that data.retryAttempts is 0 on the first attempt and 1 on the second attempt.

```
function completeOut(passed, reportParam) {
  var reportType = reportParam || reporting;
  var attemptNumber = data.retryAttempts

  if(passed) {
    switch(reportType) {
      case 'completed-incomplete':
      case 'completed-failed':
        LMSProxy.ResetStatus();
        LMSProxy.SetReachedEnd();
        break;

      case 'passed-incomplete':
      case 'passed-failed':
        LMSProxy.SetPassed();
        LMSProxy.SetReachedEnd();
        break;
    }
  } else if(attemptNumber == 1) {
    switch(reportType) {
      case 'passed-failed':
      case 'completed-failed':
        if(!isPassed()) {
          LMSProxy.SetFailed();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code didn't work. [Here's a link to the JS errors returned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdwQp.png)

----edit----
Here is a link to the SCORM package: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOJyxzBUD1A43jMykPBHUe3Knzpc_Ec6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure you've given us enough information, for instance what is `reportParam` set to? You are checking `!isPassed()` inside a conditional that is already checking that `passed` is not true (so is unnecessary). `SetReachedEnd` need not ever be called after `SetPassed` or `SetFailed` is called (without `ResetStatus`) because it is a no-op in that case. Additionally we'd need to know what function is called at the end of the content (if any), such as `Finish`, `Suspend`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Brian. (1) I've no clue what reportParam is set as or even where to find it. It's not in the doc or linked docs; (2) "if !isPassed( )" does seem repetitive; (3) I believe SetReachedEnd is executed so that if the user passes/completes the course, but then retakes it, the status remains "passed/completed" in the LMS (i.e., you can't ever go from passed to failed); (4) Finish is called at the end of the content or on any exit.

What if I add a link to the full-SCORM package in the post?

Comment: 3) `SetReachedEnd` will simply set completion to completed *if* a success status (pass/fail) has not been set during this session and then set a flag that allows for overriding the exit mode based on a global configuration flag. 4) `Finish` being called for a 1.2 package will check the completion status and without a `SetPassed`/`SetFailed` call will trigger the completion status to be set to completed. This is probably why you are seeing completed in your case.

Comment: The JS errors indicate that `data.retryAttempts` is invalid code (data is `undefined`) so `attemptNumber` can't possibly equal `1` and so the second portion of your conditional will never be entered. You need to determine what `data` should be or how to access the `retryAttempts`.